# validate field using regular expression in Field validation module

Tags: entities

I have added a text field in a content type. I'm looking to validate that field by adding a Rule using "Field Validation" module. I found few options in this module like regular expression (  Regular expression (Perl-Compatible) , Regular expression (POSIX multibyte) ). I have used this options but i'm not above to get the results. Actually i want to check a field value which matches character like numbers 0-9 and special character like ( , ) , - , + .

If the field value contains any other values, then i have to display an error message like "Invalid Input" .

I have tried using the following regular expression.

[0-9+()-]+

SCREENSHOT : 
[image]

when i check this expression in this website (http://www.regexr.com/). Its working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure you don't mean `[0-9\+\(\)-]+`? You need to escape special chars usually

Comment: @Clive , thanks for your quick reply. I have added the with pattern which you have suggested but still its not working. i have added the screenshot. can you please check it ?